# SignalR send object from client to server is not deserialized correctly

Tags: c#, json, signalr

I'm using signalR 2.0.2

I have an object in my client

```
 Class A {}
 Class B : A {}
 Class C : { public A member {get;set;}

 C obj = new C();
 obj.member = new B();
```

In both client and server I have the same json serializer option off `TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto`

when i send the object to the server it get there , however the member is show as of type A , when it should b type B.
I use the TraceWriter log and both on the client side and server side. the $type attirubte in the JSON shows the object type is B

Comment: (noticed it after answering...) possible duplicate of [Deserializing polymorphic json classes without type information using json.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19307752/deserializing-polymorphic-json-classes-without-type-information-using-json-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `member` *is*  `A` (the class definition says so). You can put a `B` there because `B` can be implicitly cast to `A` (since it inherits `A`), but content doesn't change its type (which will always be `A`).

It's the same that happens when we use generic collections like this:

```
IEnumerable<int> temp = new List<int>();
IEnumerable<int> temp2 = new HashSet<int>();
```

Both `temp` and `temp2` are `IEnumerable<int>` no matter what we assign to them (both `List<>` and `HashSet<>` implement `IEnumerable<>`).

To make it so `member` is recognized as type `B`, you have to cast it.

Comment: I agree with you , how ever I cannot cast member to type B, because after JSON  deserialization member is of type A losing all type B data.

Comment: I just stumbled across a potential dupe question which is probably what you're looking for. See my comment under the question.